# Reference UITableView from separate delegate/datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a UITableView which will be used more than once throughout the app. Because of this, I separated the delegate and datasource into a separate file which we can call Table1Controller : NSObject. Within each cell, there is another table which I separated the delegate and datasource out again - Table2Controller : NSObject.

My issue is that when a cell in Table2Controller is clicked, I need to modify each Table2 model and reload them all. I can make a new protocol to tell Table1 that one of it's embedded tables was clicked, but I still have no reference to Table1 to go through each cell and call reloadData on their Table2. I'm also not completely sure this is the best way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure, that there is no way to do the same but in one tableView with sections? So, if there is not, you can use NSNotificationCenter and send notification each time when its need to reload tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what it is you exactly mean to do; however I am getting the impression that you wish to load data from Table1Controller to Table2Controller? If this is the case you could use KVO by setting NSUserDefaults from one table to another?

Could you possibly post some code with what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion on NSNotificationCenter! I forgot about that - I added a notification for all of the second tables to reload their data.